# Set query timeout to 20mins for all mongodb database

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, devops

I have to set the query timeout for MongoDB database to 20 mins. I have below docker-compose files for the MongoDB database.

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0
    ports:
      - xxxx:xxxx
    volumes:
      - ./xxxx:/xxx/xx:xx
    environment:
      USERNAME: "xxxx"
      PASSWORD: "XXX"
    admin_iface:
    image: xxxx/xxxx
    ports:
      - xx:xxxx
    environment:
      CONN_NAME: xxxx
      DB_NAME: xxxx
      DB_USERNAME: 'xxxx'
      DB_PASSWORD: 'XXX'
      DB_HOST: 'mongodb'
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PASSWORD: 'XXX'
```

My question is, Which field I need to use to set query timeout for 20mins? Do I need to add the field in docker-compose or some other configuration file?

Does somebody please help on this? Or Do I need to add something else in the configuration file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of doing this is to specify maxTimeMS with each query on the client side.

Comment: Do I need to specify maxTimeMS  in the docker-compose file or ? Could you please let me know the correct syntax as well? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hey, could you please give me a short answer on this?

Comment: Hello, a friendly reminder could you please guide me? Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax is described in documentation.

Comment: @Shanmukh Specifying the maxTimeMS on a query would look something like
db.collection.find(...).maxTimeMS(1000 * 1000 * 1000);